# визуализация на Java

Tags: java

мне нужно написать программу, которая визуализирует размер папки и размер ее содержимого, например, в виде разноцветных прямоугольников. Подскажите что мне лучше всего использовать для визуализации?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо копать в сторону [Java FX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX)

Если сильно не заморачиваться разноцветными квадратиками, то можно воспользоваться встроенным средством визуализации каталогов - код будет приблизительно такой:

```
public class DirectoryChooserExample extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX App");

        DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
        directoryChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File("src"));

        Button button = new Button("Select Directory");
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            File selectedDirectory = directoryChooser.showDialog(primaryStage);

            System.out.println(selectedDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
        });


        VBox vBox = new VBox(button);
        //HBox hBox = new HBox(button1, button2);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 960, 600);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

[Ссылка на оригинал](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/directorychooser.html#:%7E:text=A%20JavaFX%20DirectoryChooser%20is%20a,stage.)

Если надо заморочиться, то придется заморочиться. Пишите, если есть конкретные вопросы по конкретному коду - спрашивайте.